# Information pop-out in arcview 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, html-popup

How do you get the text information to pop out with the information extracted from the Attribute Table when you hover over it or a right-click on it or something akin to that?  Example is in the picture supplied.

Are you able to extract certain columns from the AT or all the columns are automaticaly included?

When doing this, are you limited with options on how the pop-up is done?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Layer Properties of your feature, and go to the **HTML Popup** tab at the top, and check-on "Show content for this layer using the HTML Popup tool", and the "As a table of the visible fields" is a good default starting point.

Now you should see a new tool near the Measure and Info tools, called HTML Popup. See [the documentation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Setting_HTML_pop-up_properties_for_feature_layers) to get a better idea of what you can do.